# I am getting an error "Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-5-98244a0951f7> in <module>()"

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract the specific parameters by calling an api . i am able to call the api but when i extract the data it returns me only few lines of api and when i set the limit in the url it throws the error. I am new to python . can anyone please help me with that. here is my code

```
import http.client
import json

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("xxx-staging.xxx.xxx")

 headers = {'cache-control': "no-cache",
 'postman-token': "d97b415e-04ae-c8b0-12b4-c55ce883628e"  }

 conn.request("GET", "/xxxx/api/xxx/internal/2017-05-22    //aps_with_errors?&limit=50000")

 res = conn.getresponse()
 data = res.read()
 output = json.loads(data)

errorMap = []
for rea in output['results']:
errorMap.append("%s : %s " % (rea['Version'],rea['reason_code']))

with open("/result.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in errorMap: print (line)
```

Comment: Could you please also post full traceback?

Comment: I am getting below error 

<ipython-input-6-7b152023d452> in <module>()
     20 errorMap = []
     21 for rea in output['results']:
---> 22  errorMap.append("%s : %s " % (rea['FwVersion'],rea['reason_code']))
     23         #errorMap.append("%s : %s " % (rea['FwVersion'],rea['reason_text']))
     24 

KeyError: 'reason_code'

Comment: * into your question, ideally formated as code. Also, are the things I see in your comment numbers of lines?

Comment: The error occurred as version was not present in all the key fields of api resolved it by adding    if 'Version' in rea: before errorMap.append